# Attribute in Repository module

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

While using the repository module I noticed "Attribute" and "Values" in module setting. What are these settings used for? Will you explain using an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a hierarchy of categorization.

Category --> Attribute --> Value